# Need help understanding the gradient function in pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, gradient

The following code

```
w = np.array([[2., 2.],[2., 2.]])
x = np.array([[3., 3.],[3., 3.]])
b = np.array([[4., 4.],[4., 4.]])
w = torch.tensor(w, requires_grad=True)
x = torch.tensor(x, requires_grad=True)
b = torch.tensor(b, requires_grad=True)


y = w*x + b 
print(y)
# tensor([[10., 10.],
#         [10., 10.]], dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)

y.backward(torch.FloatTensor([[1, 1],[ 1, 1]]))

print(w.grad)
# tensor([[3., 3.],
#         [3., 3.]], dtype=torch.float64)

print(x.grad)
# tensor([[2., 2.],
#         [2., 2.]], dtype=torch.float64)

print(b.grad)
# tensor([[1., 1.],
#         [1., 1.]], dtype=torch.float64)
```

As the tensor argument inside `gradient` function is an all ones tensor in the shape of the input tensor, my understanding says that

1. `w.grad` means derivative of `y` w.r.t `w`, and produces `b`,
2. `x.grad` means derivative of `y` w.r.t `x`, and produces `b` and
3. `b.grad` means derivative of `y` w.r.t `b`, and produces all ones.

Out of these, only point 3 answer is matching my expected result. Can someone help me in understanding the first two answers. I think I understand the accumulation part, but don't think that is happening here.

Comment: Should I post on data science stack exchange ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find the correct derivatives in this example, we need to take the sum and product rule into consideration.

Sum rule:

[image: Sum Rule]

Product rule:

[image: Product Rule]

That means the derivatives of your equation are calculated as follows.

With respect to *x*:

[image: Derivative with respect to x]

With respect to *w*:

[image: Derivative with respect to w]

With respect to *b*:

[image: Derivative with respect to b]

The gradients reflect exactly that:

```py
torch.equal(w.grad, x) # => True

torch.equal(x.grad, w) # => True

torch.equal(b.grad, torch.tensor([[1, 1], [1, 1]], dtype=torch.float64)) # => True
```